# Using numbers as input in \newenvironment LaTeX

Tags: latex, overleaf, newenvironment

I'm trying to make an environment that builds a column vector, and that takes as input the scale factor of the distancing between the rows:

```
\newenvironment{VEC}[1]{\begin{Bmatrix}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
                       {\end{Bmatrix}}
```

I know that the `\newenvironment` command accepts as input only strings, so I tried with `\value{#1}` having no successfull result. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with `newenvironment` or arguments, you just need to switch the order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newenvironment{VEC}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}\begin{Bmatrix}}
                       {\end{Bmatrix}} 


\begin{document}

\[
\begin{VEC}{3}
4\\
6\\
\end{VEC}
\]

\end{document}
```